# Android service - android.os.BinderProxy cannot be cast to xxx

Tags: android, service, kotlin

1. I know this has been asked multiple times
2. Yes, I read all other questions/answers
3. No, nothing is working

I am binding to a service, having my custom Binder implementation. But when `onServiceConnected` is called I cannot bind `IBinder` to my custom binder and it gives me:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.BinderProxy cannot be cast to com.xxx.xxx.service.XXXService$ServiceBinder
```

This is my service and binder:

```
class XXXService : Service() {
    private val binder = ServiceBinder()

    inner class ServiceBinder : Binder() {
        override fun toString(): String {
            return "My Service Binder"
        }
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        Log.d("test", binder.toString()) // Prints correctly "My Service Binder"
        return binder
    }
}
```

Here is how I bind to the service:

```
val i = Intent(mPluginContext, XXXService::class.java)
mPluginContext.bindService(i, mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
```

This app is a plugin for one app... `mPluginContext` is context of that app. I am using the `mPluginContext` to access resources, create views, get system services..

Here is the onServiceConnected method:

```
override fun onServiceConnected(className: ComponentName, service: IBinder?) {
    if (service == null) {
        return
    }

    serviceBinder = service as XXXService.ServiceBinder // Crash
}
```

This is the manifest:

```
<service
    android:name="com.xxx.xxx.XXXService"
    android:exported="true"
    android:label="XXX Service"/>
```

Without exported attribute in the manifest it gives me `java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service`

Some of the answers on SO says - are you sure you are running the service just once? - I put log on the beginning of `onServiceConnected()` and it is printing just once.

Previously this service was bound the same way but the communication was through messages not the binder.

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**

The tricky part is the `mPluginContext`. If I start a new activity within the plugin and use the activity context it is working just fine. 
There is still the question why would a context let me bind a service, triggered a `onServiceConnected`, but gave me a wrong Binder?

**EDIT 2**

So I can call `Messenger(service)` inside the `onServiceConnected` and communicate via messages. And it works. Why can't I cast the `IBinder` to my binder? I can't change the app now and use messages. I need the binder.

Comment: I am having the same trouble, have you resolved the issue yet?

Comment: @LongLT I did not. I abandoned services and used some third party library if I remember correctly.

Comment: I found the root cause, it is because the service is running in different processes. You have to make sure both services are running in the same process.